# Trying to setup a dual monitor system - should be easy but... it's becoming a nightmare

Tags: multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

I have an HP Pavilion DT with 1 HDMI port, 2 x USB 3, 3 x USB 2 and a dvi port. Am trying to connect a main monitor (HDMI and DisplayPort, HP brand) and a second monitor (HDMI, DVI D and D-sub) to use in extended view.

Now with the main monitor connected by HDMI and D-Sub connecting the second, images are not crisp, are not overly white, and are only barely usable; I can't see lines in Excel!

Tried the 2nd monitor on HDMI and it's perfect so I think they both need to be connected via HDMI.

Have bought 4 different types of HDMI->USB adapters ranging from £10.00 (1st one) to £40 (last one) but none of them have worked. Have bought cables, HDMI, USB, DVI you name it, I've got it! What am I doing wrong? what do I need to get this to work? I thought it would be easy!

Comment: I am sure our setups are different.. but similar.  I have an HP 17" business class laptop.. I had to fight the very scenario you are playing with.  I found that playing with the settings via the intel graphics control panel instead of the built in windows one eventually led me to success.  I had to MESS WITH IT.. for a LONG TIME before I got it work correctly.

Comment: Download the latest drivers and firmware. Uninstall the current video drivers and install the newer ones.

Comment: Thank-you @music2myear for your suggestion but, have tried that already.  Have ordered yet another USB-HDMI splitter, more expensive, more options, so hoping this one will work.